# js jquery searching and leaving visible when typing name

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have this code in my html:

```
<form>
        <div style="width:530px; height:220px; overflow-y:scroll;">

              <div class="people">
                <label class="checkbox_1" for="1">
                  <img src="1.jpg" />
                  <span>
                    Jolly Bob Monumir
                  </span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="people[]" value="1" id="1" />
              </div>

              <div class="people">
                <label class="checkbox_1" for="2">
                  <img src="2.jpg" />
                  <span>
                    Jonathan Monumir
                  </span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="people[]" value="2" id="4" />
              </div>

              <div class="people">
                <label class="checkbox_1" for="3">
                  <img src="3.jpg" />
                  <span>
                    Misoury Crow
                  </span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="people[]" value="3" id="3" />
              </div>

              <div class="people">
                <label class="checkbox_1" for="4">
                  <img src="4.jpg" />
                  <span>
                    Michael Crow
                  </span>
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="people[]" value="4" class="checkbox_1" id="4" />
              </div>

        </div>                
    </form>
```

After page loads whole form should be displayed. Now I would like to have inputbox and when I type in this box letters names of people it should automatically leave visible those names (divs with classes "people") which contain letters I type.

Example: I type "Jo", divs with Jolly Bob Monumir and Jonathan Monumir should be displayed and other should stay hidden. Then when I type "Cro", Misoury Crow and Michael Crow should be visible., etc. How can I do this with jquery? thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I found this and it works like a charm!

```
$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function(){
    $('div.people').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('div.people').each(function(){
       if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
           $(this).show();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: There's several autocomplete scripts available so you don't have to code it all yourself. Check [bootstrap's typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) and [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Both can be customized to create the exact effect you're looking for.

Comment: Pleas add your answer as such instead of putting in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I found this and it works like a charm!

```
$('#search-criteria').on('keyup', function(){
    $('div.people').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('div.people').each(function(){
       if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
           $(this).show();
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) of [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

Answer (score 0):

I added a `input` field where you type:

```
<input type="text" id="people_name">
```

and jQuery code is:

```
$('input#people_name').on('keyup', function() {
  var value = this.value.trim();
    if(value.length) {
        $('div.people span').filter(function() {
            return new RegExp(value, 'i').test($(this).text());
        }).closest('div.people').show();
    } else $('div.people').hide();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/5qGQJ/3/)**

*NOTE: You may use any autocomplete plugin.*

Comment: hello, thanks, I tried this script but it doesn't work for me - object doesnt support this property or method - so I removed trim() error is not there anymore but it is not working.